# How to use self in instance variable in python

Tags: python

Its possibly a very silly question and I just do not know how to look for this solution or what to search.

What I was trying is

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, myvariable):
        self.myvariable = myvariable

    def printVar(self):
        print(self.myvariable)


class Z:
    aa = 'test'


class Y(Z):
    #xx = X(self.aa)

    def __init__(self):
        self.xx = X(self.aa)

x = Y()
x.xx.printVar()
```

it works as expected. I was wondering whether its possible to use as

```
class Y(Z):
     xx = X(self.aa)
```

Comment: If you try to run it,  you will get an error since `self` is not defined in the class scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` only refer to the own context of a class.

You can refer to `aa` with `Z.aa`:

```
class Y(Z):
    xx = X(Z.aa)
    print(Z.aa)
```

->

```
test
```